# Drupal 7 to 8 theme migration

Tags: drupal, theme

Os escribo con motivo de una migración de un tema personalizado en Drupal 7, tengo entendido que la estructura del 8 ha cambiado demasiado como para poder hacer una migración tal cual ya sea por la web o con Drush y debo reestructurarlo reprogramarlo (de php a twig y de .info a .yml), mi pregunta es: ¿no hay forma más sencilla y merece la pena intentarlo con la estabilidad que cuenta ahora las migraciones a Drupal 8?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Te paso dos enlaces. Diferencias entre 7 y 8: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/theming-differences-between-drupal-6-7-8 y ayuda para twig: https://www.zivtech.com/blog/port-your-drupal-7-theme-drupal-8 con estos dos deberías poder portar tu theme

Comment: Muchas gracias por la documentacion track3r
Pero sigo con una duda, entonces si es posible replicar un tema customizado, a pesar de que el tema padre no tenga soporte en drupal 8 verdad ? (tema Zen)

Comment: Si usas un subtema hay muchas cosas que se heredan del padre, si el padre no está portado a Drupal 8 no veo como podría funcionar

Comment: La estructura ha cambiado bastante, ademas ahora cuentas con twig de synfony un motor de plantillas potente, pero algo limitado para implementar logica, ademas segun he experimentado, es un trabajo dificil y costoso en tiempo. En cuanto a la posibilidad de migrar un tema con un padre sin soporte, ahora mismo me encuentro migrando una web con templates basada en Zen (si soporte en 8) la solucion es basarte en otra y desde 0 (Classy se recomienda para mayor estabilidad y futura compatibilidad)